# What is the structure of the hypothetical xenon octafluoride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, halides, molecular-structure, noble-gases

According to Frlec et al.,<sup>[1]</sup> theoretical studies indicated that there is a possibility (albeit slim) that neutral xenon octafluoride ($\ce{XeF8}$) might exist.

I am curious as to what structure this molecule might possibly have. In terms of hybridisation theory, I have only learnt cases up to seven-coordination ($\mathrm{d^3sp^3}$ or $\mathrm{sp^3d^3}$), where the molecular geometry is pentagonal bipyramidal. However, answers based on other frameworks (e.g. molecular orbital theory) would also be welcome.

My conjecture: could its structure possibly be hexagonal bipyramidal?

1. Frlec, B.; Holloway, J. H.; Slivnik, J.; Šmalc, A.; Volavšek, B.; Zemljič, A. An examination of the possibility of the existence of xenon octafluoride. *J. Inorg. Nucl. Chem.* **1970,** *32* (8), 2521–2527. [DOI: 10.1016/0022-1902(70)80296-2](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1902(70)80296-2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does seem to be a good body of evidence, including your reference, for the existence of xenon octafluoride.

Regarding it's structure, according to VSEPR theory as tabulated [here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~genchem/0102/spring/6winn/pdfs/VSEPR.pdf), the structure is square anti prism:

[image]

Comment: This is the xenon octafluoride **dianion** $\ce{[XeF8]^2-}$. Simple "xenon octafluoride" would be neutral $\ce{XeF8}$.